# How can I replicated Orchard CMS's script, style and cshtml file alternates for image sources?

Tags: c#, orchardcms

I know that Orchard CMS checks a list of locations for css files, javascript files and cshtml files and will use the first file that it comes to in it's list of locations.

We've used this to good effect when we need to override layouts and styles on different areas of our website.

What we need to do now is to implement something similar for images.

For example, we need something like `@Html.AssetPath("picture.jpg")` or `Asset.Include("picture.jpg")` that will look through the content folder of all the active themes and modules until it finds an image with that name and then render it.

Can anyone shed some light into this, or even point me in the right direction?

Comment: Did you try looking at the code to see how orchard does this with shapes, and shape alternates (i.e., the feature you described).

Comment: Yes I tried to look at how Script.Include works. Could you point me in the location I should be looking for how shapes and shape alternates work?

Comment: I've never tried this before, but I know that Orchard allows themes to inherit one another. Basically, you can specify in your `Theme.txt` what is the `BaseTheme` of your current theme. I know that, if you do this, your theme will use the views of your base theme if you don't override them specifically. Now, I don't know if it does the same with static files but I'm pretty sure it does. Try it and let me know..

Comment: @Ivan: I've just tried this, but can't get it to work. How should I place the image on the page? This is what I tried: `<img src="@Url.Content(Html.ThemePath(WorkContext.CurrentTheme, "/picture.jpg"))" />`. This always renders the src as inside the current theme. I had a look through the source for these methods and I can't see anywhere where it checks to see if the file exists.

Comment: Then you're out of luck - they haven't made it to work with static files, only with views. But maybe you could make it work with custom views. For example, you create a view in your base theme that only shows a single image. Then you could override that view in child themes to show a different image. The views that use this image wouldn't have to be changed since they're only using your view which would be taken from correct overridden theme.